# When or where was the term "Most vexing parse" coined?

Tags: c++, terminology

There are countless articles and blogs discussing C++'s [most vexing parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work), but I can't seem to find any with a more substantial reference than "the C++ literature."

Where did this term come from?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scott Meyers book *[Effective STL: 50 Specific Ways to Improve Your Use of the Standard Template Library](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629)* of 2001 might be first published use.

Comment: Earliest reference I can find in Google is http://episteme.arstechnica.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/6330927813/m/5650981735 which is discussing Meyers' book - so I think this is the answer. I'm kind of surprised there's not some mention of it online by Meyers himself in a newsgroup posting or magazine/journal/web article.  At least I couldn't find one.