# Explicitly passing a const object to an constructor which takes const reference to a polymorphic class

Tags: c++, constructor, explicit

I got into a problem with my classes, passing a const object (polymorphic structure) to an explicit constructor which takes a const reference to the base class of that polymorphic structure.
Here is the sample (this is not from my code, it is for explanation here)

```
class Base 
{
...
}

class Derived:public Base
{
...
}

class Problem 
{
    Problem(const Base&);
...
}

void myFunction(const Problem& problem) 
{
    ...
}

int main() 
{
    //explicit constructor with non const object
    Derived d;
    Problem no1(d); //this is working fine 
    myFunction(no1);

    //implicit constructor with const object
    Problem no2=Derived(); //this is working fine, debugged and everything called fine
    myFunction(no2);   //is working fine

    //explicit constructor with const object NOT WORKING
    Problem no3(Derived());  //debugger jumps over this line (no compiler error here)
    myFunction(no3);   //this line is NOT COMPILING at all it says that:
    //no matching function for call to myFunction(Problem (&)(Derived))
    //note: candidates are: void MyFunction(const Problem&)
}
```

It seems that it is working fine with the second version (explicit constructor call for Problem) only if i explicitly cast the Derived object to its base class Base it like:

```
Problem(*(Base*)&Derived);
```

I do not realize the difference between calling impicitly and explicitly the constructor of the Problem class.
Thank you!

Comment: You have "Base" and "Derived" switched in your second class declaration. Is that a typo? Also, does the "debugger jumps over this line" comment apply even when you compile in a `Debug` profile with no optimizations?

Comment: You are creating objects of the base class and passing them on -- you wouldn't get polymorphic behavior. You need a reference or a pointer to a base class to get the desired behavior. Casting is not a solution.

Comment: The parameter is const reference, so there is the reference for polymorphic behavior.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is you aren't declaring an object, but a function:

```
Problem no3(Derived());
// equivalent to:
Problem no3(Derived); // with parameter name omitted
```

Use:

```
Problem no3((Derived()));
// extra parens prevent function-declaration interpretation
// which is otherwise required by the standard (so that the code isn't ambiguous)
```

This is a quirk of C's declaration syntax inherited by C++.

More examples:

```
void f(int(a)); /* same as: */ void f(int a);

void g() {
  void function(int);    // declare function
  void function(int());  // we can declare it again
  void function(int=42); // add default value
  function();            // calls ::function(42) ('function' in the global scope)
}
// 'function' not available here (not declared)

void function(int) {} // definition for declarations inside g above
```

Comment: Damn, you are right. Many thanks! Though I got into the same problem some time ago I just didn't think of it now.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, this is a quirk known as **the most vexing parse**, see another [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1610551/when-where-was-most-vexing-parse-coined) as to the origin of this nickname.